# Android Studio Emulator not Working (Lenovo Yoga 370)

Tags: windows, android-studio

I have tried multiple times to fix my Android Studio emulator without any success. I have even factory reset my computer and tried it with no success. My computer is a Lenovo Yoga 370 with upgraded ram of 16gb.
Here are the details, in the image.

Any help would greatly be appreciated, as I require this program for university.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmQOi.jpg)